# How do I store a previous variable and add it to the new one?

Tags: python, variables

What I mean by the title is, lets say I have a random number set to the value of `randomnum`, and I have another variable, lets say its called `prevrandomnum`. Then I have a third, called `randomsum`, which adds the two previous ones.

Lets say I want the variable called `prevrandomnum` to always show the previous output of `randomnum`, unless there isn't a previous, in which case it equals the first one. Also, in that last situation, I'd also want `randomsum` to add `prevrandomnum` to zero, unless there is a previous `randomnum`. Sorry if I'm not making sense, I'm still somewhat new to stackoverflow, and coding as a whole. Please help!
By the way, this is in python.

Comment: This sounds very similar to computing the Fibonacci sequence -- do a search for "python fibonacci function" and see if that gives you any ideas for how you might approach this problem!

Comment: please post the code that you have tried so far, so that it would be easier to understand.

Comment: how many times are you updating `randomnum`? That info would be useful for putting it into a `for` loop. We would want to know how many random numbers to generate e.g. `for i in range(10):`

Comment: _"...unless there isn't a previous, in which case it equals the first one"_ What first one? If there was no `prevrandomnum`, that means there is no `randomnum`. I'm not sure what you mean by the "first one" in this case

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.